# Scala: Do implicit conversions work on Any?

Tags: scala, implicit, typeclass

I would like to store some objects from different type hierarchy into `List[Any]` or similar container, but perform implicit conversions on them later on to do something like type class.
Here is an example:

```
abstract class Price[A] {
  def price(a: A): Int
}

trait Car
case class Prius(year: Int) extends Car
trait Food
case class FriedChicken() extends Food

object Def {
  // implicit object AnyPrices extends Price[Any] {
  //   def price(any: Any) = 0
  // }

  // implicit object PriusPrices extends Price[Prius] {
  //   def price(car: Prius) = 100
  // }

  implicit object CarPrices extends Price[Car] {
    def price(car: Car) = 100
  }

  implicit object FoodPrices extends Price[Food] {
    def price(food: Food) = 5
  }
}

def implicitPrice[A: Price](x: A) = implicitly[Price[A]].price(x)

import Def._  
val stuff: List[Any] = List(Prius(2010), FriedChicken())
stuff map { implicitPrice(_) }
```

The above code throws an error as follows:

```
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Price[Any]
       stuff map { implicitPrice(_) }
                                ^
```

If you uncomment `AnyPrices`, you'd get `List(0,0)`, but that's not what I am expecting.
Do I have to store the manifest into the list for this to work?

Also, `List(Prius(2010)) map { implicitPrice(_) }` doesn't work either because it wants `Price[Prius]` and `Price[Car]` isn't good enough. Is there a way to make it more flexible?

Comment: Implicits are selected statically. Given the fact that your list contains unrelated types, its static type is `List[Any]`, which accounts for the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Can you suggest any workaround? `Manifest[_]#erasure.cast` returns `Any` too.

Comment: Two things: 1) I was wrong about the inferred type for your list. It's actually `List[Price]`, but you explicitly typed `stuff` as `List[Any]`; 2) The bottom line is that implicits are a statically resolved construct while you want a dynamic resolution of the price-determining method for any given product. I'd suggest perhaps a trait / mix-in approach.

Comment: Even if implicit conversions are available, the inferred type seems to be `List[Product]`. `res0: List[Product] = List(Prius(2010), FriedChicken())`. Since I could store lower type than `Product` like `String`, I was forcing `Any`, but it doesn't seem to matter because implicits only work for the type but not the supertypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looks like I can't get a type class once the objects are reduced to `Any`. My attempt of using `Manifest` also failed, since there seems to be no way for me to cast an `Any` into `T` even if I have the `Manifest[T]` object.

```
import reflect.Manifest._
def add [A, B >: A](stuff: A, list: List[(B, Manifest[_])])(implicit m: Manifest[A]) = (stuff, m) :: list
val stuff2 = add(Prius(2000), add(FriedChicken(), Nil))
stuff2 map { x =>
  val casted = x._2.erasure.cast(x._1)
  implicitPrice(casted)
}
```

gives me

```
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Price[Any]
```

so it seems like I have to resolve things into `Price` before I stick them into `List`:

```
abstract class Price[A] {
  def price(a: Any): Int
}

trait Car
case class Prius(year: Int) extends Car
trait Food
case class FriedChicken() extends Food

object Def {  
  implicit object PriusPrices extends Price[Prius] {
    def price(car: Any) = 100
  }

  implicit object FriedChickenPrices extends Price[FriedChicken] {
    def price(food: Any) = 5
  }
}

import Def._  

def add [A, B >: A](stuff: A, list: List[(B, Price[_])])(implicit p: Price[A]) = (stuff, p) :: list
val stuff = add(Prius(2000), add(FriedChicken(), Nil))
stuff map { x => x._2.price(x._1) }
```